# cl.exe preprocessor definitions aren't setting values

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive, cl

In summary, I'm trying to compile some c++ code from the commandline using cl.exe. The idea, before you ask, is to actually call this cl.exe command from another program that dynamically defines the preprocessor definitions to pass to cl.exe. Also, I am working out a redistributable cl.exe so that's why there's all of the include and lib paths.

Here's the cl.exe command:

`cl.exe /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oi /Oy- /GL /D:SERVER=\"{address}\" /D:PORT=\"{port}\" /D:PROTOCOL=\"{protocol}\" /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MT /GS- /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo:.\\Clients\\ /Fd:.\\Clients\\vc140.pdb /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt /I.\\src /I.\\Compiler\\include /I.\\Compiler\\include\\ucrt /I.\\Compiler\\include\\um /I.\\Compiler\\include\\shared .\\src\\*.cpp /link /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:\".\\Clients\\{name}.exe\" /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:.\\Compiler\\lib /MANIFEST /manifest:embed /PDB:\".\\Clients\\{name}.pdb\" /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG:incremental /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:\".\\Clients\\{name}.lib\" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt`

The important part is right in the beginning:

`cl.exe ... /D:SERVER=\"{address}\" /D:PORT=\"{port}\" /D:PROTOCOL=\"{protocol}\"`

These are the definitions I'm trying to pass into my program where the values inside of the brackets will be defined in my other program. Putting arbitrary values in there like "192.168.1.2", "4444", and "TCP" on the command line to test this provide the same result as my program so it isn't a problem there.

Here's the snippet from my C++ code trying to define the variables based on these definitions:

```
int main()
{
    std::string srv = "";
    std::string prt = "";
    std::string pro = "";

    #ifdef SERVER
    srv = SERVER;
    #endif

    #ifdef PORT
    prt = PORT;
    #endif

    #ifdef PROTOCOL
    pro = PROTOCOL;
    #endif

    if (srv == "" || prt == "" || pro == "") {
        printf("ERROR: VALUES EMPTY!\n");
        system("pause");
        return 11;
    }

    //For fun...
    printf("Server: %s\nPort: %s\nProtocol: %s\n", srv.c_str(), prt.c_str(), pro.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the cl.exe command it compiles properly but I get the "ERROR: VALUES EMPTY!" every time. I can't figure out why the definitions aren't going through.

Comment: You cannot assign values for global variables outside of any function body. That code is bogus, it doesn't _compile properly_.

Comment: @Steve Sure I've noticed that, the code sample is bogus, the question isn't useful at all in it's current form.

Comment: Yes you're right. It is a code sample. There isn't much to change to make it work but I'll do that for you.

Comment: Updated. I took out the global variables that I had and wrapped it in a main function. Anything else I can do to help this make some sense?

Comment: Assuming `cl.exe` is the VC++ compiler (which you should spell out in the question, really), the syntax doesn't use a `:` colon e.g. `/D VAR` or /DVAR will work, but not `/D:VAR`.

Comment: It turns out that I've looked at my problem entirely incorrectly. I'll post a new question if I don't find the answer in further research. However, dxiv was right about the ':' vs ' '/''. I took the error I was getting while using no separator as a problem with my compilation command. Really, the error was in my C++ code where I was trying to set a string equal to the value of the defined value from the compiler.

What I need to do now is figure out how to set a variable equal to that value passed in. Or I need to figure out a better way to do this.

Thanks guys.